# ffmpeg capture audio in raw format

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to capture audio with ffmpeg in .raw format. Here is what I do to capture in .mp3 format :

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -t 10 -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -y "sound.mp3"
```

note that I don't want to capture in .mp3 then convert in .raw

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output from your command.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4854513/1256347

Answer (score 1):

Use `sound.wav` as your output, instead of `sound.mp3`.  Or if you literally mean raw PCM data with no headers, not just uncompressed, then try

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -t 10 -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -f s16le -y "sound.pcm"
```

Play it back with

```
ffplay -channels 2 -f s16le -i sound.pcm
```

Unless you really need headerless, I'd suggest WAV files for ease of use.  Sample format, rate, and number of channels stored in the file is a Good Thing.